# Why ContentResolver does not see added files by another app?

Tags: android, file, uri, android-contentresolver, file-manager

I added files to `Documents/MyExcelsFolder`  by using `ContentResolver.insert` and then also added new file to `Documents/MyExcelsFolder` folder by another app (for ex. **FileManager**)

Then I try to get all files from the `MyExcelsFolder` folder

```
fun getAppFiles(context: Context): List<AppFile> {
        val appFiles = mutableListOf<AppFile>()

        val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
        val columns = mutableListOf(
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE
        ).apply {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                add(
                    MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH
                )
            }
        }.toTypedArray()
        val extensions = listOf("xls", "xlsx")
        val mimes = extensions.map { MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(it) }

        val selection = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            "${MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH} LIKE ?"
        } else {
            "${MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA} LIKE ?"
        }

        val selectionArgs = arrayOf(
            "%${Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS}/MyExcelsFolder%"
        )

        contentResolver.query(
            MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),
            columns,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC"
        )?.use { cursor ->
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                val pathColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
                val mimeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE)
                val filePath = cursor.getString(pathColumnIndex)
                val mimeType = cursor.getString(mimeColumnIndex)
                if (mimeType != null && mimes.contains(mimeType)) {
                    // handle cursor
                    appFiles.add(cursor.toAppFile())
                } else {
                    // need to check extension, because the Mime Type is null
                    val extension = File(filePath).extension
                    if (extensions.contains(extension)) {
                        // handle cursor
                        appFiles.add(cursor.toAppFile())
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return appFiles
    }

fun Cursor.toAppFile(): AppFile {
    val cursor = this

    val idColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID)
    val nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
    val mimeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE)
    val pathColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)

    val id = cursor.getLong(idColumnIndex)
    val uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), id)
    val fileDisplayName = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex)
    val filePath = cursor.getString(pathColumnIndex)
    var mimeType = cursor.getString(mimeColumnIndex)
    val relativePath = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH))
    } else {
        null
    }
    var type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType(mimeType)
    if (type == null) {
        type = File(filePath).extension
        mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(type)
    }
    return AppFile(
        id = id,
        uri = uri,
        absolutePath = filePath,
        name = fileDisplayName,
        mimeType = mimeType,
        extension = type,
        relativePath = relativePath
    )
}
```

And in result there are only files from `ContentResolver` added by `insert` command, and there no files copied by FileManager. How to see all files in `cursor`?

Operation system: Android 10 (Q) (API level 29)

Target API version: api 29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from Android 10 there is a new storage access model in action which is called [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage) and it is much more restrictive. In short:

1. Your app can always access its own directories.
2. Your app can write (with help of `ContentResolver.insert`) to [the shared media](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media) collections and **can read only files created by your app** from them. You can access other apps files from these collections by requesting the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.
3. Your app can access other files and directories by using [file or directory system pickers](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#grant-access-directory).

It's a bit weird and looks like a bug that you are able to access `xls` files through the `MediaStore.Files` collection. [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media) says

> The media store also includes a collection called `MediaStore.Files`.
> Its contents depend on whether your app uses scoped storage, available
> on apps that target Android 10 or higher:
>
> If scoped storage is enabled, the collection shows only the photos,
> videos, and audio files that your app has created.
>
> If scoped storage
> is unavailable or not being used, the collection shows all types of
> media files.

But anyway you still are not able to access files created by other apps as stated above.
So depending on your use case there are a few options to go:

1. As accessing files through the `MediaStore.Files` works for you now, you can try to request `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission as shown in [this table](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) to get a non-filtered access to media collections. But I would expect such way to work unreliably on different devices and/or expect to stop it working with the new updates, because the media collections are supposed to be used for media files only.
2. You can use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to show a file/directory picker to user and get access to a file or the whole directory tree. Please check [the restrictions](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#document-tree-access-restrictions) of this method also. I'd say this is the preferable way to go.
3. Android 10 allows you to [temporarily opt-out](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-scoped-storage) from the scoped storage by using the `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage` flag. But Android 11 is out already and this flag does not have any effect in it.
4. You can request the new `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission and then request a special white-listing by user to [access all files](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files). That's how the file managers work now. This feature is available starting from Android 11, so you'll likely to use the opt-out flag for Android 10. Also be sure to check the restrictions and Google Play policies on using this feature if you are going to publish your app there.