# Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() is depreceated

Tags: android, methods, directory, storage

I want to get directories from my phone storage
this is my code :

```
//"storage/emulated/0"
public String ROOT_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
public String PICTURES = ROOT_DIR + "/Pictures";
public String CAMERA = ROOT_DIR + "/DCIM/camera";
```

}

What can I put instead of the method 'getExternalStorageDirectory()' ?

Comment: Does not matter that it is deprecated. This function does its job. Use it. There is nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

In api 29 you need to use `ContentResolver`, see my question about this:
[Why ContentResolver does not see added files by another app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64276816/why-contentresolver-does-not-see-added-files-by-another-app)

To save image from internet, you need to use this:

```
val url = URL(uRL)
val urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
urlConnection.requestMethod = "GET"
urlConnection.doOutput = true
urlConnection.readTimeout = 60000
urlConnection.connectTimeout = 20000
urlConnection.connect()
val fileName = "image.png"
val uri = insertToContentResolver(context, fileName, File(fileName).extension)
val outputStream = context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)

val inputStream = urlConnection.inputStream

val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
var bufferLength: Int //used to store a temporary size of the buffer
while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { bufferLength = it } > 0) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength)
}
outputStream.close()



fun insertToContentResolver(
    context: Context,
    fileName: String,
    extension: String
): Uri? {
    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
        put(
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE,
            MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension)
        )
        put(
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
            File(
                "${Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).absolutePath}/${
                    context.getString(R.string.folder_name)}",
                fileName
            ).absolutePath
        )


    }

    return context.contentResolver.insert(
        MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),
        contentValues
    )
}
```